# Imitate button click to download file (script in form tag)

Tags: r, web-scraping, httr

I'd like to "click" the download button **Download as Excel File** from R at the website: https://envirotoxdatabase.org/. Looking at the html, I reckon there is a python script within a `<form>` tag, which should be run somehow.

Also to fill this Excel file with data, I first need to "click" on the **Search** button.

How can I do that?

[image]

My attempt:

```r
qurl = 'https://envirotoxdatabase.org'
fl = 'test.xlsx'

res = httr::POST(
  qurl,
  body = list(id = 'a2downloadform',
              action = 'https://envirotoxdatabase.org/index.php/home/downloadExcelPython',
              class = 'pull-right'),
  httr::write_disk(fl, overwrite = TRUE),
  encode = 'form'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an `rvest` session...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

sess <- session("https://envirotoxdatabase.org/") #start session

form <- sess %>% html_form() %>% pluck(1)         #find button as a form

sess <- sess %>% session_submit(form)             #click it

writeBin(sess$response$content, "test.xlsx")      #save the response
```

Unfortunately you need to click the "Search" button before downloading the excel file, otherwise it is empty. I'll update this if I can find a way of doing that with rvest, but it might not be possible.

Otherwise, we can use `RSelenium` to include the search. This works for me...

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4555L, verbose=F, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate("https://envirotoxdatabase.org/")

search_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', value = '.btn-primary')

search_button$clickElement()

download_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', value = '.pull-right')

download_button$clickElement()

remDr$close() #to close the selenium browser
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the session workflow! The thing is, I just realized that I have to "click" the Search Button first to not get an empty excel sheet back and include all the data. How would I do that? I'll change the question accordingly..

Comment: @andschar Yes, I spotted that too. I can't see an easy way of doing that, although you might be able to use `html_form_set` to add parameters to the form before submitting it. Nothing has worked for me so far, but you might have better luck. Otherwise it might be a case of using `rSelenium`.

Comment: @andschar I've added a RSelenium solution to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the RSelenium part - I'm learning a lot! However `search_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', value = '.btn-primary')` throws the error `Error in .self$value[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`. Probably b/c I'm not properly connected. Running `remDr$getStatus()` returns an empty list. I'm on Windows and behind a company proxy.

Comment: @andschar When you run the `rsDriver` line a separate firefox window should open, controlled by selenium. If you've not got firefox, you can use chrome (although I have always found it more difficult to get it working with selenium). It is possible that your company proxy is getting in the way - I'm just on a stand alone windows machine. You should also use your browser's 'inspect' function to check that the search button is indeed of class `.btn-primary`.

Comment: Ok, I use Firefox, but the window doesn't open. Chrome doesn't work either. I will dig into the Proxy settings.. But this also means that there is always a manual step involved, when you say "a separate firefox windows will open"? Thanks, I'am aware of the css selectors, the problem is rather the connection.

Comment: @andschar No, there is no manual step - it all runs from the R script, which controls the opening and closing of the browser.